# Can't assign a big number to a variable out of the while loop in scala

Tags: scala, while-loop, numbers, variable-assignment

I want to write a program that can find the N-th number,which only contains factor 2 , 3 or 5.

```
def method3(n:Int):Int = {
  var q2 = mutable.Queue[Int](2)
  var q3 = mutable.Queue[Int](3)
  var q5 = mutable.Queue[Int](5)
  var count = 1
  var x:Int = 0
  while(count != n){
    val minVal = Seq(q2,q3,q5).map(_.head).min
    if(minVal == q2.head){
      x = q2.dequeue()
      q2.enqueue(2*x)
      q3.enqueue(3*x)
      q5.enqueue(5*x)
    }else if(minVal == q3.head){
      x = q3.dequeue()
      q3.enqueue(3*x)
      q5.enqueue(5*x)
    }else{
      x = q5.dequeue()
      q5.enqueue(5*x)
    }
    count+=1
  }
  return x
}
println(method3(1000))
println(method3(10000))
println(method3(100000))
```

The results

```
51200000
0
0
```

When the input number gets larger , I  get 0 from the function.
But if I change the function to

```
    def method3(n:Int):Int = {
    ...

      q5.enqueue(5*x)
    }
    if(x > 1000000000) println(('-',x)) //note here!!!
    count+=1
  }
  return x
}
```

The results

```
51200000
(-,1006632960)
(-,1007769600)
(-,1012500000)
(-,1019215872)
(-,1020366720)
(-,1024000000)
(-,1025156250)
(-,1033121304)
(-,1036800000)
(-,1048576000)
(-,1049760000)
(-,1054687500)
(-,1061683200)
(-,1062882000)
(-,1073741824)
0
.....
```

So I don't know why the result equals to 0 when the input number grows larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Int` is only 32 bits (4 bytes). You're hitting the limits of what an `Int` can hold.

Take that last number you encounter: 1073741824. Multiply that by 2 and the result is negative (-2147483648). Multiply it by 4 and the result is zero.

BTW, if you're working with numbers "which only contains factor 2, 3 or 5", in other words the numbers `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, ...` etc., then the 1,000th number in that sequence shouldn't be that big. By my calculations the result should only be `1365`.

Comment: Use `BigInt` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/math/BigInt.html) instead of `Int` in your function. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks.It works with 'BigInt'.But actually,the number list should be 2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15.....And not contains 14 ,which is 2 * 7.